# Confusion in uncertainty relation derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Nouredine Zettili derives the uncertainty relation in his book "Quantum Mechanics- Concepts and Application". While deriving, he reaches to an equation
\begin{equation}
|\langle\Delta A \Delta B\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{4}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|^2 + \frac{1}{4}|\langle \{A,B\} \rangle|^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $A, B$ are hermitian operators
Then he goes on to say that he can drop the anti-commutator term to get
\begin{equation}
|\langle\Delta A \Delta B\rangle|^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|^2 
\end{equation}
Then he brings the Schwarz inequality to say that
\begin{equation}
{(\Delta A})^2 {(\Delta B})^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|^2 
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
{\Delta A} {\Delta B} \geq \frac{1}{2}|\langle[A,B]\rangle| \tag{2}
\end{equation}
but if I put the equation 1 in Schwarz inequality, I get
\begin{equation}
{(\Delta A}) {(\Delta B}) \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|^2 + \frac{1}{4}|\langle \{A,B\} \rangle|^2 } \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Now if $[A,B] = 0$, then Zettili's final equation becomes
\begin{equation}
{\Delta A} {\Delta B} \geq 0
\end{equation}
and mine becomes
\begin{equation}
{\Delta A} {\Delta B} \geq \frac{1}{2}|\langle \{A,B\} \rangle|
\end{equation}
Now from Zettili's final equation we can say that if $[A,B] = 0$ both operators can be operated simultaneously to get arbitrarily small uncertainty while measurement but from my final equation, that is not true. The smallest achievable uncertainty if $[A,B] = 0$ is $\frac{1}{2}|\langle \{A,B\} \rangle|$.
Is there a point I am missing which is making me reach this conclusion?

Comment: Wiki says the relation has extra terms. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish Then why does literally every Quantum Mechanics textbook use the uncertainty relation as $\Delta A \Delta B \geq \frac{1}{2} |\langle[A,B]\rangle|$ ?

Comment: Because the relation provides a lower bound. And when the commutator is zero, the variance is also zero (as can be seen from the link I provided earlier). When providing lower bound you can safely underestimate.